# SQL select customers, items from transactions with and without transaction

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables in SQL Server, Customers, Items and Transactions. C_id and I.id from table Transactions are the foreign keys from the tables Customers and Items. I want for a specific date range to see for all the customers, all the items with their quantity, either has or not transaction. When the item has not transaction the quantity will be 0.

**Customers** (C)

```
id    |  Name
1     |  C1
2     |  C2
3     |  C3
```

**Items** (I)

```
id   |  Name
1    |  I1
2    |  I2
3    |  I3
4    |  I4
```

**Transactions**

```
id   |   C_id  |   I_id   |  qty   | date
1    |   C1    |   I1     |  10    | 2/2/2016
2    |   C2    |   I3     |   5    | 3/2/2016
3    |   C1    |   I2     |   3    | 3/2/2016
4    |   C2    |   I1     |   8    | 4/2/2016
5    |   C1    |   I1     |   2    | 5/2/2016
6    |   C1    |   I2     |   4    | 5/2/2016
7    |   C2    |   I1     |   2    | 6/2/2016
8    |   C1    |   I1     | 100    | 1/3/2016
9    |   C2    |   I2     | 200    | 2/3/2016
```

The result I want for data range between 2/2/2016 and 10/2/2016 is:

```
C   |  I    | qty
C1  |  I1   | 12
C1  |  I2   | 7
C1  |  I3   | 0
C1  |  I4   | 0
C2  |  I1   | 10
C2  |  I2   | 0
C2  |  I3   | 5
C2  |  I4   | 0
C3  |  I1   | 0
C3  |  I2   | 0
C3  |  I3   | 0
C4  |  I4   | 0
```

Comment: cross join, left join, group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Hope this help you.,

```
select c.name,i.name,sum(isnull(t.qty,0))
from customers c
cross join Items I 
left join transactions t on t.C_Id = C.Id and I.Id = t.I_Id and t.date between '2/2/2016' and '10/2/2016'
group by c.name,i.name
order by c.name,i.name
```

Comment: `When the item has not transaction the quantity will be 0.`

Comment: We have the Date in Transaction Table only. So when we filter the values using Date, the item must be a transacted one.

Comment: This query returns only the items which have transactions. I don't want exactly this. It doesn't return the items for all the customers with no transactions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a full list of all customers with all items then you're going to want to cross join these two tables. You can then do a left join to the transactions table with the date range you're after.

Let's make your test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Customers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Customers
GO
CREATE TABLE #Customers (id int, Name varchar(2))
INSERT INTO #Customers (id, Name)
VALUES
(1,'C1')
,(2,'C2')
,(3,'C3')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Items') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Items
GO
CREATE TABLE #Items (id int, Name varchar(2))
INSERT INTO #Items (id, Name)
VALUES
(1,'I1')
,(2,'I2')
,(3,'I3')
,(4,'I4')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Transactions') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Transactions
GO
CREATE TABLE #Transactions (id int, C_id varchar(2), I_id varchar(2), qty int, date datetime)
INSERT INTO #Transactions (id, C_id, I_id, qty, date)
VALUES
(1,'C1','I1',10,'2016-02-02')
,(2,'C2','I3',5,'2016-02-03')
,(3,'C1','I2',3,'2016-02-03')
,(4,'C2','I1',8,'2016-02-04')
,(5,'C1','I1',2,'2016-02-05')
,(6,'C1','I2',4,'2016-02-05')
,(7,'C2','I1',2,'2016-02-06')
,(8,'C1','I1',100,'2016-03-01')
,(9,'C2','I2',200,'2016-03-02')
```

And the query you need;

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime; SET @StartDate = '2016-02-02'
DECLARE @EndDate datetime; SET @EndDate = '2016-02-10'

SELECT
c.Name Cust_ID
,i.Name Item_ID
,SUM(ISNULL(t.qty,0)) Qty
FROM #Customers c
CROSS JOIN #Items i
LEFT JOIN #Transactions t
    ON c.Name = t.C_id
    AND i.Name = t.I_id
    AND t.date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY c.Name, i.Name
ORDER BY c.Name, i.Name
```

Gives these results;

```
Cust_ID Item_ID Qty
C1      I1      12
C1      I2      7
C1      I3      0
C1      I4      0
C2      I1      10
C2      I2      0
C2      I3      5
C2      I4      0
C3      I1      0
C3      I2      0
C3      I3      0
C3      I4      0
```

Comment: Glad it helps. Feel free to upvote any answers that you consider useful and mark one as the accepted answer. Thank you